# mingw64 nothing to be done for file / no rule to make target

Tags: makefile

I am trying to build a 64 bit version of a library using mingw-w64. [here](https://bitbucket.org/libtcod/libtcod/src/ff47576c3bdf9548326fe8ba3d807b3ba13288d8/makefiles/makefile-mingw-sdl2?at=1.5.x&fileviewer=file-view-default) is the makefile i am trying to make, with these rules:

```
mingw32-make.exe -t ...\makefiles\makefile-mingw-sdl2 all
```

And here is the rule for all:

```
all : debug release

release : libtcod-mingw.dll libtcod-gui-mingw.dll upx

debug : libtcod-mingw-debug.dll libtcod-gui-mingw-debug.dll
```

I get two messages:

Nothing to be done for ...\makefile.mingw-sdl2.

*** No rule to make target 'all'. Stop.

Never worked around with makefiles so I haven't the slightest idea what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option to use a different `Makefile` is `-f`, not `-t`.

`-t` means only "touch" everything to mark it as updated. You'll always never want this option.

Because `-t` doesn't have an argument, your `..\makefiles\makefile-mingw-sdl2` is interpreted as a target to be built, and as this exists and `make` doesn't know any prerequisites for it, there's nothing to do to build it, and `make` is telling you this with the message

> Nothing to be done for ...\makefile.mingw-sdl2.

For the second message: Either there is no `Makefile` in your current directory or it doesn't contain a rule for `all`.

---

What you **want** is `mingw32-make.exe -f ..\makefiles\makefile-mingw-sdl2`

Next time you run into a problem, I suggest to *at least* read the output of `mingw32-make --help`. For anything else, GNU make also has a good [online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html).